# Qt Creator's intellisense thinks that min and max were defined even though they weren't

Tags: c++, qt, c-preprocessor, qt-creator

In my code I have

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```

But whenever I use `std::max` or `std::min` the intellisense **underlines the line with red**, even though the compiler does not complain about it. If I change the code to

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>

// make sure they min/max weren't defined
#if defined(min) || defined(max)
#error "min or max were defined"
#endif

// but intellisense still thinks they were, 
// so this is needed
#undef min
#undef max
```

the problem disappears. But defining `NOMINMAX` prevents `windows.h` from defining min/max, so why is intellisense thinking that they were defined, even though they were not? And I've checked, the preprocessor error I've added is never hit.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't understand `NOMINMAX`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I recently uninstalled QtCreator from this machine, but could it be so that QtCreator unconditionally indexes `windows.h` before anything, if you have that kind of project? What happens if you define -DNOMINMAX in comipler settings?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It does, I've checked that, too. If I add an `#ifndef NOMINMAX` its body is grayed out, and if I remove `#define NOMINMAX` the body is no longer grayed out.

Comment: @RomanSaveljev I added NOMINMAX to the .pro file, but it didn't help. You might be right, I had been thinking the same, probably header files in the standard library paths are parsed only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,  I did not uninstall it. It helps to sort out indexer if I add `DEFINES+=NOMINMAX`

...and then CLOSE and RE-OPEN the project. Even though QtCreator told 'Parsing' after every change to .pro file I did not see immediate effect. Looks like if you re-open the project it does better 'Parsing'

My QtCreator version is 2.6.1 and I use Qt5.0.0

Comment: This should probably be filed as a bug to the Qt developers.

Comment: It fixed it for me. Restarting Qt Creator really was required. As for filing a bug, I don't know how to do it. Is it very time-consuming?